# How do I turn a Pandas DataFrame object with 1 main column into a Pandas Series with the index column from the original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Say I have a simple data frame as below where I set the index of this dataframe to be the time column.

*E.g*

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2021-02-20','2021-02-21','2021-02-22','2021-02-23'], 'price':[1,2,3,4]})
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

Now this dataframe as only 1 main column (price) so I want to know the best way to take this dataframe and simply change its type to a series.

I feel like this can be done using the pandas `squeeze()` method however want to know if there are any other alternatives or better ways, also correct me if my method seems wrong.

*E.g*

```
# Setting the original DataFrame to a Series, since only 1 main column can use the 'column' argument
# in the squeeze method 

df = df.squeeze('columns')
` ``
```

Comment: I see no problem with the ```squeeze```. Usage: ```df["price"].squeeze()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplier is select column like:

```
s = df.set_index('time')['price']
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: Thanks but when you select column like that does it make it a series? like if I do `type(s)` would it appear as a Series rather than a DataFrame?

Comment: @nishcs sure, then s is series.

Answer (score 1):

`df["price"]` would also give you the same thing.